# Web2py Zappa AWSLamda

Tags: aws-lambda, web2py, python-zappa

Can someone please tell me, How can I deploy the Web2py Application to AWS Lamda using zappa. The configuration for django is somewhat this:

```
{ 
"dev": {
  "django_settings": "frankie.settings", 
  "s3_bucket": "zappatest-code" 
  } 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.